# Forms authentication only for admin area in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have already read many topics about it but i can't find a solution.
I'm working on asp.net mvc 5 application with an admin area.

I have created a filter inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute` and i have added it as attribute on my controller.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var errorResult = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                { "controller", "Login" },
                { "action", "Index" },
            });
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = errorResult;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

LoginController uses `AllowAnonymous` attribute.

I tried to login but then the request is not authenticated (i see it in debug mode). I need to edit web.config.

If i add the following code in root web.config:

```
 <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Login" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

it works but my application has not any login, only admin area has.
What is the solution? 
I can't write this code in web.config area.
Thanks in advance.